# How can an ASP.NET website authorize using Active Directory Groups without login prompts?

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-6

I want to build an intranet website that doesn't login-prompt a user that is already logged in to the AD (on a company computer in the same domain as the IIS server). So far, all my attempts have resulted in a basic login prompt or not being able to read HttpContext.User.Identity.Name. The User object would then be used to check if that user is a member of a certain Active Directory group in the domain.

I've seen different solutions that require the user to add a Trusted site in the browser or registry edits. That is not what the product owner would like. **Would it be possible to create a completely automatic experience (the user would have had to log in to their computer anyway)?**

**MyAuthorizeAttribute**

The code below is found inside my custom AuthorizeAttribute that is put on the index method of my home controller. This shouldn't matter though, because it works once there is a User object and the controller is called. Users that are members of the group will continue to the start page, others wont.

```
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<domain name>");

            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            if (userPrincipal != null)
            {
                if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "<group name>"))
                {
                    // The user belongs to the group
                    return true;
                }
            }
            // The user is not a member of the group, handle the unauthorized request
            return false;
```

**Web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />    
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

**IIS**

Site:

- Authentication: only Windows enabled (I've tried with anonymous but I can't retrieve any User info)

  - *edit:* Provider: NTLM

Application Pool:

- .NET 4.0.30319
- Integrated
- Identity: Network Service (I've tried app pool as well, but one solution suggested network service)

Comment: Sadly I haven't gotten this to work, but I will create an answer if I figure it out. We will probably go with the login prompt version though.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, within the context of Windows Auth, the user's roles are equivalent to their AD group memberships. As a result, you can simply use the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` and remove your custom one entirely.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "<domain>\<group>")]
```

There's not enough to work with here to tell you what the actual problem you're having is, but removing custom stuff you added, which is always prone to failure, is a good first step in reducing the variables.

Comment: Even though it doesn't help with the login prompt problem, thanks for the tip! I think I would have to make a custom attribute anyway, to handle unauthorized requests my own way and such. But this will look so much more readable.

Comment: I am wondering, if I want to authorize at application/site level, what should I do? Trying not to define the Authorize attribute at each controller. Thanks.